# PHP::DOTNET loading throws error every other page load

Tags: php, .net, iis-7

I am currently testing a dll that I have created in vb.net inside php.  I am loading it through php's dotnet com object.  It loads up fine the first time.  But if i hit f5 and refresh the page it will throw up this error.

`HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly`

It does this sequencially.  First time loading works fine, second - fails, third - works fine, fourth - fails and so on.  It's pretty consistent.  Almost like this object is not being disposed of effectively.  I've never used this before so please let me know if I have to escape it in some way.

```
$myclassobj = new DOTNET("MyWebClass,"
."Version=1.0.0.0,"
."Culture=neutral,"
."PublicKeyToken=6fe1ba5eac63c19c"                   
,"MyWebClass.MyAssembly.Web");
echo $myclassobj->SayHello("Hi PHP!!!!");
```

This is being tested on my local computer which is running windows 7, IIS 7, with php 5.3.19

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever work this out? Mine is doing exactly the same thing. Sometimes it works fine, other times it doesn't!

Comment: Please have a look at the end of my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653541/error-every-second-time-i-make-a-xmlhttprequest-to-a-php-file-using-dotnet), it might help you. I think it's a bug...